# When using socket.io and react, express the value comes in multiple times

Tags: node.js, sockets

this is **client(react)** code

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:8000", { transports: ["websocket"] });
const Home = () => {
  socket.emit("server");
  socket.on("server", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And this is **server(express)** code

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user changmin");
  socket.on("server", (data) => {
    io.emit("server", { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 });
  });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

when i see console log in chrome developer tool, log show like this

```
{value: 7}

{value: 7}

{value: 9}

{value: 9}
```

How to solve this error? Same value come twice also another value come one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I fix **next.config.js** like this

```
reactStrictMode: false,
```

reactStrictMode option default is true , but change to false.
Also I use useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("server");
    socket.on("server", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Like this I can see only one time value!!